# How to limit space reserved for MDI child form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a main form in .Net.
The main form should incle some MDI child forms

In the main form I have a picture in the top that I want to be always seen.

When the child forms are maximized, the picture is hidden. Is there any way to limit the maximized space of the child forms when they are maximized ?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to tell us how the picture is being displayed?  PictureBox?  Is it Docked = Top?

Comment: It's a picturebox indeed, dock : none

Comment: you can use a table layoutpanel in the MDI parent to control who gets how much space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docking controls to the sides of an MDI Container will automatically reduce the area of the MDI client area.

So in your case, you either dock the PictureBox control to the top:

```
pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Top
```

or a container control, such as a Panel, and then place the PictureBox or any other child control inside that.